# Issue while applying COUNT condition in UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I used COUNT Condition to find the number of punctuations in an annotation.But I didn't received the expected output.

```
             DECLARE Sentence(INT pmcount);
             "Conflicts of interest"->Sentence;

             DECLARE SentenceLastToken;
                     Sentence{-PARTOF(SentenceLastToken)->MARKLAST(SentenceLastToken)};
             INT Pmcount=0; 

             Sentence->{ANY+?{->SHIFT(Sentence,1,1,true)} SentenceLastToken{PARTOF(PM)};};
             Sentence{COUNT(PM,Pmcount)->Sentence.pmcount=Pmcount};
```

**Sample Input:**

```
 Conflicts of interest.
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  Conflicts of interest
       pmcount:0
```

**Received Output:**

```
  Conflicts of interest
       pmcount:1
```

I'm facing this problem only if there is any PM after the Annotation value.

Comment: This is a bug in UIMA Ruta 2.6.1 and will be fixed as soon as possible.